# How to select key name dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable as follows:

```
var test={
    line1:"1",
    line2:"2"
}
```

How can I access those keys dynamically ? like I want to do :

```
test."line"+1 ="3";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's

```
test['line'+1] = '3'
```

The dot syntax does not allow computed keys.

Answer (score 0):

`test.line1=3;`

will do the necessary.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation), since you have a variable key

```
test["line"+1] ="3";
```

Answer (score 0):

To access keys like that, you need to use the square bracket syntax eg

```
test["line" + 1] = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to acces elements you have to correct the code like this

```
test["line"+1] ="3";
```